# What is the best data model for list of activities created by users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in firestore. I'm trying to design the data model for my app. And i want to know what is the best way to design data model when i have a list of users and list of activities that the users created. Is this the correct model? As i think in this manner it will be easier to display. Any suggestion or improvement please let me know. Thank you for your advice.

```
activities(collection)
  -- userid1(document)
     ---- activityid1
          ---- type : hiking
          ---- timestamp
          ---- comment: comment-text
     ---- activityid2
          ---- type : jogging
          ---- timestamp
          ---- comment: comment-text
  -- userid2
     ---- activityid1
          ---- type : hunting
          ---- timestamp
          ---- comment: comment-text
```

Comment: There is no overall "best way" to model data with nosql databases.  The model that works is the one that satisfies the queries that you intend to make.  You have to know your queries before you can create an effective model.

Comment: I would store all of the activity documents under one collection named activities and set a field of the userID of the current user making that activity. Then you can make calls to firestore with the `where()` method and only get activities for a specific user but also have the capability to fetch all activities and display then in a feed. For example you could set a flag saying whether or not the activity is private or public and then show public activities as a feed to other users. Your querying capability gets limited when you sub collection activities. hope this can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's hard to tell what the best way is, it depends on your project needs and what you need to do with the data.

*NOTE: A document is also limited in size to 1MB.*

I'm not sure what the list of activities is, but if you need to store activities for each user that will scale and continue to grow, then I would personally recommend placing activities as a sub-collection under the document of each user. The reason is that, unlike Firebase Realtime Database, querying in Firestore is shallow by default so that will result in fast speeds and save some costs while fetching data.

I think this [blog post link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html) will lead you to get some general ideas for structuring your data model.

Hope this helps you.